# How to input a (at) as character

Tags: symbols

I would like to have symbols like `#` and `@` in text both occasionally and in a paragraph way. I have tried `\#` for occasional usage, but no idea how to input an (at) as it is.

```
\begin{verbatim}
    @
\end{verbatim}
```

The above is for paragraph, what about occasional (at) in a line? The first one is given by simple `@`, the second one is given by verbatim.

[image: pdf]

Comment: Also simply `@` should work, otherwise: `\MVAt` from `\usepackage{ marvosym }`. See http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html

Comment: @CarLaTeX a simple `@` prints like a company band. looks quite different from the rest characters.

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228)

Comment: is there a way to write characters as it is like `verbatim` but just built in a line?

Comment: Use `\texttt{...}` or `\ttfamily`

Comment: @CarLaTeX yea, I think \texttt is best for @, how about other staff like `<([{\^-=$!|]})?*+.>` I know this sounds silly, but I am writing a regex manual for our team, so...

Comment: See Ignasi's answer

Comment: tina as has been said you can use `\texttt` but the comment that `@` looks different to other characters seems strange, `@` is not special in any way `@` gives you @ in the current font, just as `g` gives you `g` in the current font `\texttt{@}`  is `@` from the monospace font, just as `\texttt{g}` is the g.

Comment: If you write a regex manual, may be you want to look to [`listings`](http://ctan.org/pkg/listings)  package and use its `\lstinline` command instead of `\texttt` or `verbatim`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `\verb` command. You use some symbol to delimit what you want to be written like verbatim.

```
\documentclass{article} 

\begin{document}

This is the at symbol: \verb+@+. 

And this is another one: @

\verb@<([{\^-=$!|]})?*+.>@

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: What about `\texttt{@}`?

Comment: `\verb` has the disadvantage that you can not use this in arguments such as titles etc, and it serves no purpose for `@` which is not a special character for latex, `\texttt` is a better recommendation.